# pkg installer error in macOS 12.3: rights in /Library/Application Support

Tags: install, python, package-management

Are there any changes in the rights of the folder `/Library/Application Support` starting with macOS 12.3?

Our application refuses to install, our postinstall script fails to create a folder (and files in it) in `/Library/Application Support`.

Our `installer-gui-script` specifies `auth="Root"` and our postinstall script (postflight python) triggers this: `os.system('mkdir /Library/Application\ Support/***')`

I don't find anything about this in the release change log for macOS 12.3. Everything was fine in previous macOS versions.
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run the mkdir from the command line and what is its return code? Also where is your python? 12.3 does not include python so you would need to bundle it with your app

Comment: You're right, the install script is a python script with #!/usr/bin/python as first line. I transformed it into a Shell script

Answer (score 1):

In macOS 12.3, apple removed the depreciated python 2.x

My installer used postinstall script in python calling /usr/bin/python

I changed my script to a Shell one and the issue is now gone